# Upgrading to .9, aliasing modules no longer works to the right of = sign when in declaration file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

After upgrading to TypeScript .9 my libraries module aliasing no longer works.

Example:
**foo.d.ts** or **foo.ts** (can be either extension)

```
declare module Foo {
    export class Bar {
    }
}

import Baz = Foo;
```

**app.ts**

```
/// <reference path="foo.d.ts" />

var a = new Baz.Bar(); // Compiler error on Baz "Could not find symbol 'Baz'"
var b: Baz.Bar; // Works just fine, no compiler error
var c: Baz.Bar = new Baz.Bar(); // Compiler error on second Baz "Could not find symbol 'Baz'"
var d = new Foo.Bar(); // Works just fine
```

Also note that it doesn't have to be "new xyz" it's any reference to Baz to the right of the equal sign.

Now if I take the code inside **foo.d.ts** and place it into **app.ts** no compiler error is thrown.  I'm thinking this is a compiler issue but am I missing something?

**Update:** I've created an Issue report for this: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest TypeScript release 0.9.1 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/06/28/announcing-typescript-0-9-0-1.aspx